# Unsupported Operand type for differentiation equation

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

```
import math
import decimal

n=5
s=3.5*n -14

def float_range(start, stop, step):
  while start < stop:
    yield float(start)
    start += decimal.Decimal(step)

initial=list(float_range(-14, 15, s))

def diff(f, x):
    dx = 1e-6
    r1 = f(x + dx) - f(x)
    f_x = r1 / dx
    return float(f_x)

def sinc(x):
    if x==0 :
        return
    else :
        return math.sin(x)/x

def Dsinc(x):
    Dsinc=diff(sinc,x)
    return Dsinc

def nraphson(f, Df, x, dx) :
    x1= x - f(x)/Df(x)
    while abs(x1-x) < dx: 
        x=x1
    print(x1)

for x in initial :
    print(x, nraphson(sinc,Dsinc,x,1e-6))
```

code written for a school project. Numpy cant be used and all differentiation and newtons methods have to be coded in instead of using numpy functions.

does anyone know why i am getting : 
**TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'NoneType'** in line 16 at 
`r1 = f(x + dx) - f(x)`

thanks

Comment: In `sync` you have `if x == 0: return`, meaning that when `x` is `0` the return value will be `None`, which is what seems to be happening in your program.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but brackets are heavily tied up with callable functions, so python is trying to run a function represented by f, in your case with a float, with arguments x + dx. That will give you an error. However you are clearly doing a maths problem so the multiplication symbol is needed to tell python that the brackets mean multiply not call this function with these arguments. This worked in the python shell for me:

```
def diff(f, x):
    dx = 1e-6
    r1 = f*(x + dx) - f*(x)
    f_x = r1 / dx
    return float(f_x)
```

The return works because float is a built in function and f_x you defined. Hope this helps.